# Ouputting the binary tree in using in-order and pre-order traversal

Tags: python, binary-tree, inorder, preorder

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None):
        self.data = data
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
 
def inorderTraversal(root):
 
    if root is None:
        return
 
    inorderTraversal(root.left)
    print(root.data, end=' ')
    inorderTraversal(root.right)
 
def preorderTraversal(root):
 
    if root is None:
        return
 
    print(root.data, end=' ')
    preorderTraversal(root.left)
    preorderTraversal(root.right)
 
def construct(start, end, preorder, pIndex, dict):
 
    # base case
    if start > end:
        return None, pIndex
 
    root = Node(preorder[pIndex])
    pIndex = pIndex + 1
 
    index = dict[root.data]
 
    root.left, pIndex = construct(start, index - 1, preorder, pIndex, dict)
 
    root.right, pIndex = construct(index + 1, end, preorder, pIndex, dict)
 
    return root, pIndex     

def constructTree(inorder, preorder):
 
    dict = {}
    for i, e in enumerate(inorder):
        dict[e] = i
 
    pIndex = 0
 
    return construct(0, len(inorder) - 1, preorder, pIndex, dict)[0]
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
 
 
    inorder = [4, 2, 1, 7, 5, 8, 3, 6]
    preorder = [1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 7, 8, 6]
 
    root = constructTree(inorder, preorder)
 
    print("The inorder traversal is ", end='')
    inorderTraversal(root)
 
    preorderTraversal(root)
```

I have this code which construct the binary tree, but in no way it can display the tree in the terminal. It is hard to do! Is there anyone here who could add a method which can display the binary tree in a terminal?

For the above example, it might look like

[Binary Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNfAG.png)

[image]

Comment: There is a library called, `binarytree`, which will generate random trees or you can provide your own. It will also generate it visually within the terminal, https://pypi.org/project/binarytree/

Comment: Yeah it's pretty hard. You might want to consider doing it non-recursively. You can create a stack. For each node you add its right and left chlidren to the stack. Then at some point all elements of the stack would belong to the same 'level' (height-wise). You pop and print all of them, until the stack is empty (then you know a level has been printed). You could first get it to simply print each level on a new line, without any fancy slashes. Slashes and spaces/indents are the harder part

Comment: Check out this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-level-order-traversal-line-line/. Unless you really need the slashes, maybe just leave it at that

Comment: This feels like it could be a  homework assignment  check out this link for more information about binary trees https://medium.com/@ajinkyajawale/inorder-preorder-postorder-traversal-of-binary-tree-58326119d8da

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implemented algorithm for solving your task. For example tested output on same data as your picture has, try on bigger amount of numbers to see more beautiful picture.

In my algorithm both width and height of each sub-tree and length of edges are adaptive.

Those who knows Russian language may read my [other post](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1222334/267338) regarding same topic, binary tree construction in console. That other post implements several visualization algorithms in C++. If you don't know Russian at least you may copy C++ code from there.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVPtbhshEPzvp9h/QE3t5qNJVdWvkBewLXSyuYQKc9EetdKnd3eBO7ioSNbinZ1hdg/e/8a3ITzcbiffjSO8DGf7cwW0zrYHY1xw0Rg5Wt9rOHex0@BtH3cvQ7Aa0L2@5b3KJF5cu@FS2CXGEmA2ARyWQNIiJMUZWrGNd3QhmojWykD@VDXoQrDYJnm5HjgDjtsJtgK80MY/GGB/rKeTSTp3jFkoWVcz6qlLQutBqQOl20yyXCkn4pwwNRmk9DAgSCG0UvtvR6VzFpfZaoZol@5DZo0m7ykxelaVI3ylM2ANdwq2W7jXUyr/rRxkDlYOLuuxSsycKxXvBQj4QlbWeTZrKIk6s@vGfkQbzrLUJkFHP9Kj8q2YSW7ecd@sRxWLL9LUHQ6V2Er2NCxHEwfswqslhD2rZmzVjyxePQ/I792x2qfp0dVw8CtZoWlZP9oJ/L@rxjNMysjKuFDGhTJ@Ul7ofmqFv3V2owtXtX2V23pNifQMpDgEsfk9uCCby68qZeX43YbuYo2B3Q6EMZfOBWNEfgg4DHzd@aHLO53jfYmPSpXdQ4nfS3yegB9zydN0avM8WTwnb7d/)

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None):
        self.data = data
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        
def print_tree(node):
    def inner(node):
        if node is None:
            return []
        sdat = str(node.data)
        l, r = inner(node.left), inner(node.right)
        cl, cr = len((l or ('',))[0]), len((r or ('',))[0])
        s = max(cl, cr)
        sll, slr = (s - cl + 1) // 2, (s - cl) // 2
        srl, srr = (s - cr) // 2, (s - cr + 1) // 2
        v = [' ' * s + sdat + ' ' * s]
        v.extend([' ' * (s - i - 1) + '/' + ' ' * i + ' ' * len(sdat) +
            ' ' * i + '\\' + ' ' * (s - i - 1) for i in range(s // 2)])
        v.extend([(' ' * sll + l[i] + ' ' * slr if i < len(l) else ' ' * s) +
            ' ' * len(sdat) + (' ' * srl + r[i] + ' ' * srr if i < len(r) else ' ' * s)
            for i in range(max(len(l), len(r)))])
        return v
    print('\n'.join(inner(node)))
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Node(1, Node(2, Node(4)), Node(3, Node(5, Node(7), Node(8)), Node(6)))
    print_tree(root)
```

Output:

```
       1
      / \
     /   \
    /     \
   2       3
  4       / \
         5   6
        7 8
```

---

First algorithm above was done using preorder. I'm providing 2nd algorithm using inorder. It has a different simpler output:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVLbTsMwDH3vV/gtDWQgGAOE1F/YF0yyqjZlkTq3StMHJP69xE3WZGJ5OZaPL8eOxx93Hmi/LE1fTxMch1Z/FeBfqztANGQcYjnpvlPQ1q5W0OvOVceBtAJrvs/BliGJH8c@cShUa8YtwdmeYLgl1lqeWXGjCpYxWkMOndW6JK9PJoGGSNvVqeBBwTxa76xACAVNZrebnek0HXAiGJ6adCL4We1mSyl26xN0plah9CMIgF@hbmo0/0OeMzGZG4TcMtdhy@ZK7nbCw@Rid16olPd08UaTrDkvfl9WFnI6ZbrmfKLQKrVJrQvD90H1RSNC5XeLeKkNIYqwSTsM/J18UOWLCvga8U3KaO0jHiJ@XInPLeRdxoGzM@DisliWPw)

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None):
        self.data = data
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        
def print_tree(node):
    def inner(node, *, upref = '', cpref = '', dpref = ''):
        if node is None:
            return
        inner(node.right, upref = dpref + '  |',
            cpref = dpref + '  /', dpref = dpref + '   ')
        print(cpref + '--' + str(node.data))
        inner(node.left, upref = upref + '   ',
            cpref = upref + '  \\', dpref = upref + '  |')
    inner(node)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Node(1, Node(2, Node(4)), Node(3, Node(5, Node(7), Node(8)), Node(6)))
    print_tree(root)
```

Output:

```
     /--6
  /--3
  |  |  /--8
  |  \--5
  |     \--7
--1
  \--2
     \--4
```

---

Implementing 3rd algorithm that does preorder, but it is much simpler than 1st algorithm:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVLBTsMwDL33K3xLAx0SDAZC6pXjThwnWRFzWaTOrZLsgMS/lzgp6SZ2wJeX5tnPz07Hr3AYeD1NH73xHrbDnl4riLGnDhAt24BYe@q7BvYmmAZ66kK7HZgacPbzkM86F0lI7p2kQpsqLgmpjoTAJZG0IpOwUJXYGJ3lgMER1Rz96cWgZSaXLhu4idaMF4l3d4rfo4sJLSh15s12IMlgZVKmhZBwFE6Oy1XqWieVW6jVbrdSUp96UO8J1PdK6cj5kC2kobVemhVzebji783E8mKwdAD40wDUdT1Z3/Vx/6W2KC3qlZX3ZnMkRGjj3hCPxjKiyltywyDN5Aep75uMDzM@aj2f1jM@zfj8S7yUlI2eXZw9q4jrapp@AA)

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None):
        self.data = data
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        
def print_tree(node):
    def inner(node, *, last = True, pref = ''):
        if node is None:
            return
        print(pref + ('\\-' if last else '|-') + str(node.data))
        inner(node.right, last = False, pref = pref + ('  ' if last else '| '))
        inner(node.left, last = True, pref = pref + ('  ' if last else '| '))
    inner(node)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Node(1, Node(2, Node(4)), Node(3, Node(5, Node(7), Node(8)), Node(6)))
    print_tree(root)
```

Output:

```
\-1
  |-3
  | |-6
  | \-5
  |   |-8
  |   \-7
  \-2
    \-4
```

Comment: Is that hard to do the same job for inorder-postorder and preorder-postorder? Can you modify the question to make it works for the two other cases? Do you prefer I start another question?

Comment: @Robert It is possible to output to console only in one way. No other ways. There is no preorder/postorder/inorder when outputting to console. Only processing tree in your code may use inorder/preorder. But console output is just a helper function, it is not related to way of processing data inside tree. In other words output to console can be done for anything - inorder/preorder/postorder.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67062345/adjust-constructtree I think this question is for you. I know I can create such tree using inorder and postorder traversal for instance. I don't think we have to modify `print_tree()`, but rather modify `constructTree()`

Comment: @Robert I understood what you want. Just updated my answer, added 2nd part with 2nd algorithm. 1st algorithm uses preorder, 2nd uses inorder. Please put a look.

Comment: This is not really what I want. What you have done prints the tree once it is constructed. Suppose it is not built yet. Suppose I have `inorder=[3, 7, 1, 10, 9, 5, 8, 6, 4, 2]` and `postorder = [3, 7, 10, 9, 1, 8, 4, 6, 2, 5]`. How would you print the tree using the information. `constructTree()` would do that, but it is not adapted for inorder-postorder. So I need a version of that function which would work with both inorder-postorder and preorder-postorder.

Comment: @Robert I just updated my answer with 3rd preorder algorithm of outputting to console. And just saw your comment. I have to think about what you actually mean here. I think if you're given preorder or inorder data then you have to build recursively your tree first and then use my functions to output to console. So it is a work for `construct()` function to support innorder/preorder data, it is not console-outputting function duty. Console-outputting function should only accept already built tree. If you want me to implement `construct()` function then tell me, it will not be difficult.

Comment: The two other print functions were not necessary, but it is nice to have those. I would like if you can adapt the code from my question so that it can also build the tree for the cases inorder-postorder and preorder-postorder. We cover just the case inorder-preorder so far, not the two others. You can add your answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67062345/adjust-constructtree