# Adjust construct() function

Tags: python, binary-tree, inorder, preorder, postorder

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None):
        self.data = data
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
 
def construct(start, end, preorder, pIndex, dict):
 
    # base case
    if start > end:
        return None, pIndex
 
    root = Node(preorder[pIndex])
    pIndex = pIndex + 1
 
    index = dict[root.data]
 
    root.left, pIndex = construct(start, index - 1, preorder, pIndex, dict)
 
    root.right, pIndex = construct(index + 1, end, preorder, pIndex, dict)
 
    return root, pIndex     

def constructTree(inorder, preorder):
 
    dict = {}
    for i, e in enumerate(inorder):
        dict[e] = i
 
    pIndex = 0
 
    return construct(0, len(inorder) - 1, preorder, pIndex, dict)[0]
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
 
 
    inorder = [4, 2, 1, 7, 5, 8, 3, 6]
    preorder = [1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 7, 8, 6]
 
    root = constructTree(inorder, preorder)
 
    print("The inorder traversal is ", end='')
    inorderTraversal(root)
 
    preorderTraversal(root)
```

This code constructs a tree with the preorder and inorder traversal. How can I modify that code to make it work for inorder-postorder and preorder-postorder? I guess I just have to modify `construct()` and create `constructPreOrderInOrderTree()` and `constructPreOrderPostOrderTree()` in a similar manner.

**EDIT**

Suppose I have `inorder=[3, 7, 1, 10, 9, 5, 8, 6, 4, 2]` and `postorder = [3, 7, 10, 9, 1, 8, 4, 6, 2, 5]`. `construct()` would do that for inorder-preorder, but it is not adapted for that example. So I need a version of that function which would work with both inorder-postorder and preorder-postorder.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by `inorder-preorder` and `preorder-postorder` and `inorder-postorder`? I can understand what just inorder or preorder or postorder mean, but not combined.

Comment: Ohh yes! If I give you `inorder=[3, 7, 1, 10, 9, 5, 8, 6, 4, 2]`, you cannot rebuild the binary tree completely. You would need something else to build the binary tree completely.     `inorder = [4, 2, 1, 7, 5, 8, 3, 6]` and `preorder = [1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 7, 8, 6]` would generate the binary tree from that question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67059333/ouputting-the-binary-tree-in-using-in-order-and-pre-order-traversal/67060989?noredirect=1#comment118539616_67060989

Comment: @Arty Look at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/construct-tree-from-given-inorder-and-preorder-traversal/ if you want to understand a bit more.

Comment: But algos code is already provided on GeeksForGeeks site. StackOverflow experts don't need to invent something, just take code from there. For example here is [inorder-postorder](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/construct-a-binary-tree-from-postorder-and-inorder/) algo. I think preorder-postorder is also available on theirs site.

Comment: BTW, are you sure that `preorder-postorder` variant of task is solvable? Did you invent this task yourself or is it a part of geeksforgeeks practice problems dataset? Can you point a link to `preorder-postorder` problem description on GeeksForGeeks site?

Comment: I thought it would be difficult to solve your tasks, but today decided to make a try and it appeared that your tasks are very easy, please put a look at [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67085956/941531), I implemented all 3 construction algorithms - preorder-postorder, preorder-inorder, inorder-postorder.

Answer (score 0):

Changes:

- Use a variable name like `lookup` to avoid overshadowing an existing type name (e.g. `dict`)
- Go from right to left

  - Start from the end
  - Decrement pIndex along the way
  - Update pIndex from the opposite direction

```py
def construct_post(start, end, postorder, pIndex, lookup):
    # base case
    if start > end or pIndex < 0:
        return None, pIndex
 
    root = Node(postorder[pIndex])
    
    # go from the right to the left instead
    pIndex = pIndex - 1

    index = lookup[root.data]

    # update pIndex going in the opposite direction
    root.right, pIndex = construct_post(index + 1, end, postorder, pIndex, lookup)
    root.left, pIndex = construct_post(start, index - 1, postorder, pIndex, lookup)

    return root, pIndex


def constructTree_post(inorder, postorder):
    lookup = {e: i for i, e in enumerate(inorder)}
    pIndex = len(postorder) - 1

    # start from the end
    return construct_post(0, len(inorder) - 1, postorder, pIndex, lookup)[0]
```

The resulting tree:

```
          1
       /     \
     2        3
   /        /   \
  4        5     6
          / \
         7   8
```

Answer (score 0):

Without even reading Geeks-for-Geeks pages I decided to implement my own algorithms for construction functions (preorder-postorder, preorder-inorder, inorder-postorder).

All my algorithms are `O(N^2)` complexity.

Besides construction functions (`construct_preorder_postorder()`, `construct_preorder_inorder()`, `construct_inorder_postorder()`) I also implemented traversing functions (`traverse_preorder()`, `traverse_inorder()`, `traverse_postorder()`), console tree printing function (`print_tree()`) and Node equality comparison function (`__eq__()`).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1VZtbtswDP3fU/Cf7VXZ6nZfCNAr7AJpYHixshpz5U5SBgzY3TORkhUqkZuuw4AtQCBRpMhH6lHy4w97P6qb/X4ztMbAp7GTywtwv05uoWl61dumKY0ctgK61rYCBrm1cOsslRSg@y/3k1T5jfhD@9do7lQ4pIrgAYdUMXmjkaGQ3yKG0d5LzSJpaXdaQcki3nojL7Wq40EnHUlOF/0cY5gMSayi2QUCsrr9LrWRrjqj7qQulatawDThWa2h3wIqoDdUHpCDkdFR1gfBquASViRhAmsn5W09sjloj1q@GNtM9MRlhDqjPoNuNPbPS5d6ySBK9R5SWt0jgJtRGat3GxuzYU7ckgAUA17XL1JbMKO2skNthbSZRLQj9g1SRSXOjbQkVwKYS/Lo0ubWVyc0x2LkLOuMZSdRvboKOepxtK55XXf5VUFjvSbldtTQC3AFVyDV7kHq1sqS5RpiSkpimXTNYJzP3pW1Tpa1AZ@vr8QCavcfTGLzWcv268UxakIa7ej8MV1DJSEqnD2nVb2sHaLBrH15V0s3rU6d6t9yutBmOTlcYDpOXtTr6jyJpsal83bCcxiEZs8jEFr@i/w5JMrpg45yDMqzh6rw18nDzodTxy2/lDncY@ANeqPpPGHCLsY7t/LEpUPVmbt0JuXEGZSRMweXCRVo7/NYM5nO0QYbJOWNRt74vokddP1fcyd7VMSWF105eXdP3zhEnkfdK9tYLSV/S1HTKxWePgGvBOwcFbeuMkUhYMPmXZynBecPcFpzX7ODbYzjn9hDKO/6EgqAn4VIfGxOTd4wMGwZikO7ULLlZlIuFoUbXAXL@KKz3mK48NPgAGvHnedhMZO7O4ZrxzMK/RPDsLbu8bNVtQ@yafC4i6Z5aHvVNIWvJNX21rOuFn68DuNbbFKa3YTxXRg/TIqP0eR9FRI@pkFY9LcR3T1@EvnlwpeZT6rks1HMfOqK2S@5NG6D/I7BgxR3kJzAOPcCH@fA2uvpKzitQnZbtgHz8Sp@Eye54lnzbFFO86Wt@/0v)

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, left = None, right = None):
        self.data = data
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self.data == other.data and self.left == other.left and
            self.right == other.right)
        
def traverse_inorder(node):
    return ([] if node is None else
        traverse_inorder(node.left) + [node.data] + traverse_inorder(node.right))
        
def traverse_preorder(node):
    return ([] if node is None else
        [node.data] + traverse_preorder(node.left) + traverse_preorder(node.right))
        
def traverse_postorder(node):
    return ([] if node is None else
        traverse_postorder(node.left) + traverse_postorder(node.right) + [node.data])
        
def construct_preorder_postorder(pre, post):
    assert sorted(pre) == sorted(post) and len(pre) == len(set(pre)), (pre, post)
    if len(pre) == 0:
        return None
    if len(pre) == 1:
        return Node(pre[0])
    root, l = pre[0], pre[1]
    for i, e in enumerate(post):
        if e == l:
            ls = i + 1
            rs = len(post) - 1 - ls
            break
    return Node(root,
        None if ls == 0 else construct_preorder_postorder(pre[1:1 + ls], post[:ls]),
        None if rs == 0 else construct_preorder_postorder(pre[-rs:], post[-1 - rs:-1]))
        
def construct_preorder_inorder(pre, ino):
    assert sorted(pre) == sorted(ino) and len(pre) == len(set(pre)), (pre, ino)
    if len(pre) == 0:
        return None
    if len(pre) == 1:
        return Node(pre[0])
    root, l = pre[0], pre[1]
    for i, e in enumerate(ino):
        if e == root:
            ls = i
            rs = len(ino) - 1 - ls
            break
    return Node(root,
        None if ls == 0 else construct_preorder_inorder(pre[1:1 + ls], ino[:ls]),
        None if rs == 0 else construct_preorder_inorder(pre[-rs:], ino[-rs:]))
        
def construct_inorder_postorder(ino, post):
    assert sorted(ino) == sorted(post) and len(ino) == len(set(ino)), (ino, post)
    if len(post) == 0:
        return None
    if len(post) == 1:
        return Node(post[0])
    root, r = post[-1], post[-2]
    for i, e in enumerate(ino):
        if e == root:
            ls = i
            rs = len(ino) - 1 - ls
            break
    return Node(root,
        None if ls == 0 else construct_inorder_postorder(ino[:ls], post[:ls]),
        None if rs == 0 else construct_inorder_postorder(ino[-rs:], post[-1 - rs:-1]))
    
def print_tree(node):
    def inner(node, *, upref = '', cpref = '', dpref = ''):
        if node is None:
            return
        inner(node.right, upref = dpref + '  |',
            cpref = dpref + '  /', dpref = dpref + '   ')
        print(cpref + '--' + str(node.data))
        inner(node.left, upref = upref + '   ',
            cpref = upref + '  \\', dpref = upref + '  |')
    inner(node)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    node = Node(1, Node(2, Node(4)), Node(3, Node(5, Node(7), Node(8)), Node(6)))
    print_tree(node)
    preorder, inorder, postorder = (
        traverse_preorder(node), traverse_inorder(node), traverse_postorder(node))
    preorder_cons, inorder_cons, postorder_cons = (
        construct_preorder_postorder(preorder, postorder),
        construct_preorder_inorder(preorder, inorder),
        construct_inorder_postorder(inorder, postorder),
    )
    assert preorder_cons == inorder_cons == postorder_cons
```

Output:

```
     /--6
  /--3
  |  |  /--8
  |  \--5
  |     \--7
--1
  \--2
     \--4
```